# Custom Button (Send Fax) for Case object doesn't appear

Tags: custom-button

I am a new Salesforce admin. I hope to find some directions.

My org installed Opero Sent/Received Fax. They appeared to be objects Sent Fax and Received Fax. We did not want to have the objects. We only want to create a button as "Send Fax" for our team.

I created a "Send Fax" field in the Case object.
I created a custom button "Send Fax" with properties as: [image]
I added the button to Page Layout: [image]

It doesn't appear in case when testing it. However, if I set the button as "Detail Page Link" it will work.

I added the Button to other places. Here are some more screenshots.[image] [image] [image]

I think I am missing lots of knowledge here, but could anybody give me some directions.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you check if you have overridden the global publisher layout for "Quick Actions in the Salesforce Classic Publisher" and "Salesforce Mobile and Lightning Experience Actions"?

Comment: Welcome to SFSE.  Please take a moment to read [ask] and take the [tour].  Have you checked with Opero support?

Comment: I have checked with Opero @DavidCheng and they don't have any FAQ on this.

Comment: @CloudConnect checked, and I am actually not sure what I am looking for in the Global Publisher Page Layout.

Comment: I found out the answer. It's the Object Lightning actions have been overridden by the Lightning App builder page. I added the Action. It works.